# on checked checkbox set attribute otherwise remove attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change a `disabled` attribute on a button, in case the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="terms" class="styled" name="terms">Accept <a href="#">terms of service</a>
```

would be checked, the `disabled` attribute should be deleted, otherwise it should stay on the button element.

I got it working the following way:

```
if(document.getElementById('terms').checked) {
    $("#registerButton").removeAttr('disabled');
}else{
    $("#registerButton").attr('disabled','disabled');
}
```

Sadly this will only work once. Once i check the checkbox the button would not be changed. Is there such a function is onchange edit the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like following.

```js
$('#terms').change(function() {
    $("#registerButton").prop('disabled', !this.checked);
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="terms" class="styled" name="terms">Accept <a href="#">terms of service</a>

<button id="registerButton">Register</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript :

- attach an handler for the change event to the checkbox
- set the disabled button property to the value of current checked checkbox property

The snippet:

```js
document.getElementById('terms').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  document.getElementById('registerButton').disabled = !this.checked;
});

document.getElementById('registerButton').disabled = true;
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="terms" class="styled" name="terms">Accept <a href="#">terms of service</a>
<button type="button" id="registerButton">registerButton</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

this will help to you. refer this working demo.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>

</style>

<body>

<input type="checkbox" id="terms" class="styled" name="terms">Accept <a href="#">terms of service</a>
<button id="mybutton" disabled>Click on me</button>


<script type="text/javascript">

$("#terms").on('change',function(){
 var check_checkbox = $(this).prop('checked');//check the checkbox status

 if(check_checkbox == true)//if it is checked
 {
  $("#mybutton").prop('disabled',false)
 }
 else//if it is not checked
 {
  $("#mybutton").prop('disabled',true);
 }
})


</script>
</body>

</html>
```